# Why is Layout triggered on document element?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, semantic-ui

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot that Layout is triggered on root element (#document) in every frame which causes next operations like paint.

This Layout is caused by Recalc Style which I am not able to understand why it's happening. There's no script running. Just Recalc Style > Layout > ...

I need to know why such Recalc Style could occur without script?

Additional Information:

- This page is using [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) framework
- It contains a custom grid
- This Recalc Style > Layout operation is performed in ever frame even when the page is idle.

Comment: Please provide more information about the page, there could be any number of reasons. Please update your question.

Comment: This page is using semantic ui. This recalc operation is going in in every frame even when page is idle. There's a custom grid in the page as well

Comment: Please update your question with more detail and explain what semantic UI is.

Comment: If your page has something like `<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>` then your page *does* have JavaScript....

Answer (score 1):

First, is this even a problem? Unless you're experiencing performance issues, don't waste time trying to prematurely optimize.

Next, enable the [Chrome rendering settings](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings) to show a what areas of the screen are GPU layers and what parts are being repainted.

Style recalculation and painting can happen for many reasons that have nothing to do with javascript. Browser resizing, tables performing rel-layout as new items are loaded during the page load, etc. Since you didn't provide any information about the page that's being loaded, it's hard to say.

My guess would be that you've got some kind of CSS animation that's being applied to a property other than translation, rotation, scale or opacity. All of those properties are GPU accelerated and won't trigger repaints, however, fading background colours, changing border thicknesses, even adjusting `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties all cause repainting.

You've mentioned that you're using Semantic UI. Either Semantic or one of its themes are causing this redraw to happen. Your screenshot doesn't actually prove that scripts aren't being called.